# Python como puedo imprimir este formato pero al revés?

Tags: python

tengo el siguiente código en Python.

```
def P(n):
if n == 0:
    yield[]
    return

for p in P(n-1):
    p.append(1)
    yield p
    p.pop()
    if p and (len(p) < 2 or p[-2] > p[-1]):
        p[-1] += 1
        yield p

generador = P(5)
for i in generador:
    print(i)
```

Ahora lo que imprime esto es lo siguiente:

[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

[2, 1, 1, 1]

[2, 2, 1]

[3, 1, 1]

[3, 2]

[4, 1]

[5]

Lo que necesito es que mi código imprima lo mismo pero al revés, que inicie por el [5] y termine con [1,1,1,1,1], alguien tiene alguna idea de como hacerlo con ese código que tengo?

Comment: Puedes convertir el generador en una lista y usar la función [reversed](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#reversed) para invertirla. Sin embargo, tiene el costo de cargar todo en memoria. Otra forma, sería modificar el código de tu generador para que genere al revez.

Comment: Para guardarlo en una lista seria:
lista = list(generador)??
Porque ya intente voltear la lógica del programa y nada mas no me queda jeje  :(

Comment: Exacto! Y entiendo...

Comment: Alguien que me pueda ayudar no entiendo muy bien su funcionamiento logico del programa?

Comment: Y lo que dije no te sirvió?

Comment: No bro rompo la funcionalidad de los generadores pasándolo a una lista  :s